# how to implement fancybox in php mysql gallery, gallery is path from upload folder

Tags: php, jquery, css, mysql

I made a gallery with php and mysql database. Gallery fetch from path from upload folder. Everything is working as it should, but when try to implement fancybox it won't use the default fancybox class.

Here is my code without href tags

```
<?php
    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or
    die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("mosornew");
    $id = isset($_GET['cid']) ? $_GET['cid'] : '';
    $res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM galerijaslika WHERE cid='$id'");
?>

<?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {?>
        <img src=" <?php echo $row['pic_path'];?> " style="width: 225px; height: 180px; margin-bottom: 5px"/>
        <?php
    }
?>
```

My question is how to implement fancybox to work with this line

```
<img src=" <?php echo $row['pic_path'];?> " style="width: 225px; height: 180px; margin-bottom: 5px"/>
```

I am trying to follow the [fancybox documentation](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/) but the picture won't popup for me.

Answer (score 0):

Include all libraries as mention in documents:
change your code while portion to following

```
    <?php
    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or
    die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("mosornew");
    $id = isset($_GET['cid']) ? $_GET['cid'] : '';
    $res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM galerijaslika WHERE cid='$id'");
    ?>

    <?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {?>
<a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="<?php echo $row['pic_path'];?>"><img src="<?php echo $row['pic_path'];?>" alt="Image not found!" /></a>
        <?php
    }
    ?>
```

and add this javascript function to your page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox();
});
```

if you include all libraries properly then i am sure it will work

Comment: HI Dani thanks for quick answer
I alredy try this you wrote but it wont open in fancybox popup
Picture is opening from folder upload it is same open like http://dreamatico.com/data_images/mountain/mountain-5.jpg
but in adress bar show a path where pic is

Comment: I check again everything, remove an add again libraries. Try to remove javascript a try to click on pic is behave the same as with javascript and get the same result like in link i send in previous massage

Answer (score 0):

You should provide HTML output, not PHP code. I suspect the problem is with your links -

```
src=" <?php echo $row['pic_path'];?> "
```

See the extra spaces?

The output of your code probably would be like `src=" image.jpg "` but it should be like `src="image.jpg"`.